# I have some code to list the options in the radio button list but I can get only the radio button but I cannot get Value

Tags: html

My code is

```
<form>

        First Nme:<br>
        <input type="text" name="name"><br>
        Age:<br>
        <input type="text" name="age"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" ><br>
        Click Gender:<br>
        <input type="radio" name="male" value="Male"><br>

    </form>
```

the above code is only showing the radio button image only but it is not showing the value which is I given "Male" is not showing, Please advise me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```html
<form >
  <label for="male">Male</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="male" value="male"><br>
  <label for="female">Female</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="female" value="female"><br>
  <label for="other">Other</label>
  <input type="radio" name="gender" id="other" value="other"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Please go through the link https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp to learn more about html.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The input tag just creates the radio button. The form will work even without the radio button and when inserting in the database, it will be "Male". But for clarity, we need text beside the radio button and so it should be,

```
<input type="radio" name="male" value="Male">Male<br>
```